# Permuting function value at some set of points change Lebesgue integral?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Consider a space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mu)$ with sigma algebra $\mathcal{F}$, and a sigma finite measure $\mu$. I have a measurable function $f: \Omega\to \mathbb{R}$, where the codomain is equipped with all Lebesgue measurable sets as the sigma algebra.

> Suppose $f \in[0, +\infty]$ or $f$ is integrable (I don't think it matters, it might). For a set $A \in \Omega$, and a bijection $\phi: A \to A$, we can extend $\phi$ to $\Omega \to \Omega$, where $\phi(x) = x$ when $x \not \in A$. If $g: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ is defined as $g(x) = f(\phi(x))$, and it is measurable, I wonder when will $\int f \, d\mu = \int g \, d\mu$?

I don't have much intuition on this, but of course, even in the finite case, the measure can be different for $\{ a \}$ and $\{ b \}$, where $a,b \in \Omega$. However, if $\Omega = \mathbb{R}$, or some other cases, I cannot think of a counterexample when $A$ has non-zero measure.

I was thinking that we can permute the order of summation for a convergent or non-negative series and wondered if we have similar conclusions for Lebesgue integral. This might be a known result that I haven't encountered yet,

Comment: If $A$ has measure zero. Otherwise let $f$ be a step function, $f=1$ on the interval $[0,1]$ and $f=2$ on $[2,4]$. Then $\mu f = 5$ but $\mu g = 4$, where $\mu$ is Lebesgue measure. By the way, you don't want to do integration with the codomain having the $\sigma$ algebra of Lebesgue measurable sets. You want it to be the Borel sets

Comment: @Andrew Thank you for the example. Are the more general criteria? The series case clearly does not have measure zero. Also, why should I change it to Borel sets?

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/31603/why-do-probabilists-take-random-variables-to-be-borel-and-not-lebesgue-measura/32260#32260

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens very rarely.  For simplicity, take $\mu$ to be the Lebesgue measure.  You're asking when $\int f(\phi(x)) dx = \int f(x) dx$.  Use $u$-substitution with $u = \phi(x)$ to see that probably won't happen most of the time.

For a more explicit example, still using the Lebesgue measure, let $\Omega = [0,1]$.
Then $\phi(x) = x^p$ is a bijection for any $p > 0$, but $\int_0^1 f(x) dx \ne \int_0^1 f(x^p)dx$ in general.